# Inspect live objects/stack in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, callstack

In node.js, is there something similar to `inspect.stack()` and `inspect.currentFrame()` from Python?
Like, capturing code context/frames/inspecting live object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `new Error().stack` to inspect the stack:

```
console.log(new Error().stack);
```

prints:

```
Error
    at repl:1:13
    at sigintHandlersWrap (vm.js:22:35)
    at sigintHandlersWrap (vm.js:96:12)
    at ContextifyScript.Script.runInThisContext (vm.js:21:12)
    at REPLServer.defaultEval (repl.js:313:29)
    at bound (domain.js:280:14)
    at REPLServer.runBound [as eval] (domain.js:293:12)
    at REPLServer.<anonymous> (repl.js:513:10)
    at emitOne (events.js:101:20)
    at REPLServer.emit (events.js:188:7)
```

There is node debugger that you can run with:

```
node debug script.js
```

See:

- https://nodejs.org/api/debugger.html

And you can also use Chrome developer tools for live inspection of everything with:

```
node --inspect script.js
```

See:

- [Debugging Node.js in Chrome DevTools](https://mattdesl.svbtle.com/debugging-nodejs-in-chrome-devtools) by Matt DesLauriers
- [Debugging Node.js with Chrome DevTools](https://medium.com/@paul_irish/debugging-node-js-nightlies-with-chrome-devtools-7c4a1b95ae27)
   by Paul Irish

Comment: Oh, that helped a lot. Thanks!